# typeahead.js common empty template for multiple dataset

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I have a typeahead js working well with multiple datasets.

I have used header template for each datasets.

I also understand that, I can use empty template for each dataset.

I use 6 datasets for this. So, If there is no matching, I would see 6 empty messages.

But, I only need one ( common for all 6 ) , is it possible ?

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: no , I did not get any.